# Why isn't array element changing position?

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers to be sorted in ascending order.

```
def sort(list):

    n = len(list)
    for outer_iteration in range(1, n):
        for inner_iteration in range(1, n):
            number1 = list[inner_iteration - 1]
            number2 = list[inner_iteration]
            if number1 > number2:
                list[inner_iteration - 1] , list[inner_iteration] = list[inner_iteration] , list[inner_iteration - 1]


list = [10,47,1,0,-39,-5]
sort(list)
print(list)
```

This works perfectly fine. But when I change the tuple that swaps the element positions, the array is no longer sorted.

```
def sort(list):

    n = len(list)
    for outer_iteration in range(1, n):
        for inner_iteration in range(1, n):
            number1 = list[inner_iteration - 1]
            number2 = list[inner_iteration]
            if number1 > number2:
                number1 , number2 = number2, number1

list= [10,47,1,0,-39,-5]
sort(list)
print(list)
```

I checked on PythonTutor and it seems to me that in the 2nd block of code, the numbers assigned to `number1` and `number 2` really do swap around, but only in the variables, not in the list.
I used tuples in both cases to swap and since `number1` and `number2` were assigned to `list[inner_iteration - 1]` and `list[inner_iteration]`, why does the second case behave differently from the first?

Comment: `number1, number2 = number2, number1` only reassigns the names `number1` and `number2`. The underlying values they're supposed to represent are abandoned when they're made to point at something else

Comment: In Python, we call these *lists*.

Comment: Anyway, please read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html .

Comment: Related: compare the two functions `def f(l): l = l + [3]` and `def g(l): l += [3]`. It looks like they do the same thing; but they do not. Try them out and try to understand the difference!

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Is it correct to say that because I was making changes (swapping) to integers which are immutable, therefore the changes made to `number1` and `number2` cannot be seen on `list[inner_iteration-1]` and `list[inner_iteration]`? Hence the list was not updated?

Answer (score 2):

So in the second code snippet, you are just changing the variables number1 and number2 to some new value (in your case you are just swapping the values). But **those values are not references to the numbers in the array** at those positions, which means the change doesn't get reflected in the array. To update the values in the array, you need to re-assign the numbers back to the array after the variables are changed.

```
def sort(array):

    n = len(array)
    for outer_iteration in range(1, n):
        for inner_iteration in range(1, n):
            number1 = array[inner_iteration - 1]
            number2 = array[inner_iteration]
            if number1 > number2:
                number1 , number2 = number2, number1
            array[inner_iteration - 1] = number1
            array[inner_iteration] = number2

array = [10,47,1,0,-39,-5]
sort(array)
print(array)
```

The above corrected code will help you understand the reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a simple example:

```
a = 5
b = a
b = 3
print(a) # prints 5
```

In this case, `b = a` does not mean `b` is always equal to `a`. If you reassign `b` to a new value sooner, `a` keeps its first value.